# Conditional aggregation in python/pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Amount  Month   Type
15      201801  Sale
34      201801  Purchase
 4      201801  Sale
86      201801  Purchase
23      201802  Sale
55      201802  Purchase
29      201802  Sale
...
```

I want to aggregate it by month such that I get:

- **Total Sales**: Sum(Amount where Type == Sale)
- **Total Sales (Running)**: Sum(Amount where Month <= Current Month and Type == Sale)
- **Total Purchases**: Sum(Amount where Type == Purchase)
- **Total Purchases (Running)**: Sum(Amount where Month <= Current Month and Type == Purchase)

So... Something like this:

```
Month  TotalSales TotalSalesRun TotalPurch TotalPurchRun
201801 19         19            120        120
201802 52         71            55         175
```

I've played with a few things, but I am new to lambda functions and I suspect that's where I need to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am using `concat`

```
s1=df.groupby(['Month','Type']).sum()
s2=s1.groupby(level=1).cumsum().add_prefix('running')
s=pd.concat([s1,s2],axis=1).unstack()
s.columns=s.columns.map('_'.join)
```

Or let using `pivot_table`

```
s1=df.pivot_table(index='Month',columns='Type',values='Amount',aggfunc='sum')
Yourdf=pd.concat([s1,s1.cumsum().add_prefix('Rolling')],sort=False,axis=1)
Yourdf
Type    Purchase  Sale  RollingPurchase  RollingSale
Month                                               
201801       120    19              120           19
201802        55    52              175           71
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`GroupBy.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) for aggregate, reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) values with cumulative sum by [`DataFrame.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Month', 'Type'])['Amount'].sum().unstack().add_prefix('Total')
df2 = df1.join(df1.cumsum().add_suffix('Run')).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df2)
Type    TotalPurchase  TotalPurchaseRun  TotalSale  TotalSaleRun
Month                                                           
201801            120               120         19            19
201802             55               175         52            71
```

Last if need column from `index`:

```
df2 = df2.reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df2)
    Month  TotalPurchase  TotalPurchaseRun  TotalSale  TotalSaleRun
0  201801            120               120         19            19
1  201802             55               175         52            71
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use groupby for this. Alternatively, use conditions in slicing the dataframe.
For example,

```
total_sales = sum(df["Amount"][df.Type == 'Sale'])
```

Comment: using built-in, pure python `sum` will be slow. Use `.sum()` at the end for a vectorized sum